# Asp.net Core 2 publish project on IIS returns just a blank page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, publish

I am working on a Asp.net core 2.0 project and i publish it and want to run on IIS.
When the project runs for first time on IIS the database created automatically and seed some tables on IIS and everything is ok. But nothing will by displayed and just returns a blank page without any error.

**web.config :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule"     resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\LibraryProject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: b874d2d9-471b-494a-828c-257173c5a413-->
```

**and Program.cs :**

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                SeedData.Seeding(userManager, roleManager, context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }     

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
         WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseKestrel()
               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .UseIISIntegration()
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .Build();

}
```

Also i created `logs\stdout` folder in publish folder near other dll`s.
I set up IIS from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x). what is wrong in my project?

Comment: any answer??!!!

Comment: 1) We don't get paid here, so you get helped when you get helped. Don't be obnoxious. 2) A blank page is usually a 404, as you have to configure the status code middleware to actually handle things like 404s. It could also be something like a 401 or 403. 3) There's not enough here to help you regardless. Do your own research, add logging, inspect the response from your developer console in your browser.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks a lot, my project created and developed by asp.net core 1.1 and after that migrate to asp.net core 2. Can this be problem?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. Find out what's *actually* happening first: is this a 404? If so, check your routing. Is this a 401 or 403? Check your auth. Is it actually coming back as 200 but still blank? Check your action/views. Do you have any client-side errors? Perhaps a JS library or code is blocking. There could be a thousand different causes. Again, do your own investigation. Once you figure out the problem, we can potentially help you solve it, if you still need help.

Comment: You can get better debug output if you change stdoutLogEnabled="false" to stdoutLogEnabled="true"

Comment: @scourge192 Thanks a lot, i could solve it by log errors

Answer (score 0):

If you've created your project from the current set of templates, Application Insights is enabled. This fixed it for me:

In your Program.cs add the following method to the WebHost.CreatDefaultBuilder:

```
.UseApplicationInsights()
```

Found here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/92979/some-aspnet-core-projects-fail-to-add-the-applicat.html

Comment: and how does that looks in the code ? Where exact must I put this method ?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late to the game here but I don't see anyone else answering.  Hopefully this will help someone.

When you see just a blank page and have no response other that the blank page, it can be caused by one of two things.  I am sure there are others but these are the two that I have seen:

1. A corrupt web.config
2. A web.config that is clashing with IIS.  This could happen when a particular section is locked in your IIS configuration.